# No puedo crear referencia a un servicio

Tags: webservice, webforms, visual-studio-2019

Uso Visual Studio 2019, me enviaron un programa de Web Forms bastante antiguo, hay 4 proyectos, en uno ha un servicio que debo consumir en otro proyecto de la solución, cuando trato de crear la referencia

```
http://localhost/Sibo.Examen.Service/Service.asmx
```

me contesta:

> Error al descargar
> 'http://localhost/Sibo.Examen.Service/Service.asmx/$metadata'. No es
> posible conectar con el servidor remoto No se puede establecer una
> conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha
> conexión 127.0.0.1:80

Intenté poniendo el url en el navegador y dice que no se puede conectar.

Desactivé el firewall pero sigue pasando.
Parte del código del servicio:

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public DataTable Get()
        {
            ClientBLL oClient = new ClientBLL();
            IEnumerable<Client> lClient= oClient.Get();
            return ToDataTable<Client>(lClient.ToList());
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public Client Post(string Identification, string Name, string LastName)
        {
            
            Client eClient = new Client { Identification = Identification, Name = Name, LastName = LastName };
            ClientBLL oClient = new ClientBLL();
            var newClient = oClient.Post(eClient);
            return ((newClient != null) ? newClient : null) ;
             
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para poder consumir ese servicio antes debes iniciar el servicio, es decir ese proyecto. Si no lo inicias depurando o sin depurar no vas a poder consumirlo.

Comment: Eso lo hice, debí mencionarlo... lo ejecuté y abrí otro VS, desde ahí traté de crear la referencia

Comment: Y en qué puerto se inicia. Lo puedes ver en propiedades del proyecto